# Visual Studio Visual Basic webforms. How to create a timer sub that calls upon another sub once a day

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, timer

I have a SQL/Oracle query sub that I want to automate. Basically, I have a webform that has a Oracle query that is allocated into a data table and is set as a data source for a gridview table. The name of the Function sub is CaqOnSQL() that returns the datatable. What I want to do is set a timer sub that is triggered once a day, when the trigger occurs I want to run the function sub again (which has a Char Date equal to the current date so that the information is updated based on the day). Since I am using webforms I have no access to tool box in my webform.aspx.vb to create a timer.

```
   Public Sub Timer_ticker_days(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim minutes As Double = 0.5
        Dim t As New System.Timers.Timer(60000 * minutes)
        AddHandler initateOQ(), AddressOf initateOQ
        t.Start()
    End Sub


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Protected Sub initateOQ()

        Try

            GridView1.DataSource = CaqOnSQL1()
            GridView1.DataBind()

            GridView2.DataSource = CaqOnSQL2()
            GridView2.DataBind()

        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.ToString)
        End Try


    End Sub
```

Comment: Is it feasible to do the query as a separate console app that you can attach to a windows scheduled task too?

Comment: VERY confused what you mean no timer, and then you have posted code based on a timer? (what gives - have a REALLY bad day????). The problem of course that you have ZERO means to know if a web page is going to remain loaded - user might pull the plug on their laptop and the web page will thus not exist and time out. Worse is maybe no users hit the web site. and if 20 users hit the web site, which one of them do you want the timer to run on? I would set a flag in some table. If more then 24 hours pass, then you re-run the query - that way first user hitting the site will trigger the update.

Comment: Better is the other suggestion: A separate console application and then use the server side task scheduler to run that separate program once a day  - such a program and process will thus not rely on some web page having been loaded. Web pages are state-less and VERY transient in nature - not something that you can hope on a wing and prayer might still be running or even have been loaded once a day. I would test a last run/update date value and and update last run. That way the first user of the day will trigger the code. Better yet as noted create a separate program and task for this.